# Using OR operator in rowCount

Tags: php, pdo

I've got a query and when I run it, I use `rowCount` to check if it returns a result. If it does, I echo some text. If not, I redirect the user - this worked fine until.... I tried to check if either `rowCount` returned a result in the same line of code, like this:

```
$id = '1';
$check1 = $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$check2 = $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

if($check1->rowCount() > 0 || $check2->rowCount() > 0) {
echo 'Hello';
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
```

I've manually gone into `table1` and `table2` and there is a result there, however when I execute the script above, I'm re-directed to index.php because apparently, there is no result.

I'm wondering if this line of code has any syntax errors:

`if($check1->rowCount() > 0 || $check2->rowCount() > 0)`

Comment: You're not executing `$check1` or `$check2`, your'e executing `$stmt`... why does `$stmt` even exist?

Comment: @MarkBaker I was under the understanding that PDO queries required `$stmt`. Also, the query worked fine when it was just one of them... that's why I believe the problem is `if($check1->rowCount() > 0 || $check2->rowCount() > 0)`

Comment: Well, implicitly you are executing check1 and check2 too, since they are references to the same statement (that's how objects work). And it's easier to copy code this way, but it is indeed unnecessary, you need *a* variable to store the statement object in, so you can execute it, but that variable doesn't have to be called `$stmt`. It's just commonly used in examples.

Comment: All that extra `$stmt` variable does is make your code more confusing. PDO can't possibly know what kind of variables you are using, so the extra one is superfluous.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen So `$stmt` isn't required in any query? I can go straight to `$con->prepare`?

Comment: @bobjomes: You'll need to use something to keep a reference to the statement, like your `$check1` and `$check2` for instance.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Ah, I understand.. so if I give the query a variable like `$check`, I won't need `$stmt`

Comment: `$check1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID=:id");
$check1->bindParam(':id', $id);
$check1->execute();` (and the $check2 equivalent) is perfectly adequate, and doesn't involve suplicating references that can confuse different queries

Comment: @bobjomes: I think it would be a good idea to read about how functions and variables work before starting to use a complex library such as PDO if you thought that having a variable with a certain name could possibly change the outcome of the program...

Answer (score 0):

A better approach for you is to use  two scalar ,COUNT(*) subqueries and add together.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `ID` = 1
   ) +
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM  `table1`
    WHERE `ID` = 1
   ) AS Result
```

If either of the table shows result Result will > 1 so you can test for it.

With PDO regular, unnamed, placeholders with "lazy" binding when possible - passing data into execute are simpler to use & will dramatically shorten your code. NOTE the parameters passed in execute() must match those in query thus $id **must** be passed twice.

I have altered your code

```
$id = '1';
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM `search`WHERE `ID` = ?)
+ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `search1`WHERE `ID` = ?) AS Result");
$stmt->execute(array($id,$id));
if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){
echo 'Hello';
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`PDOStatement::rowCount()` does **not** return the number of rows returned from a `SELECT` query. It's for calculating number of rows affected by `UPDATE` or `DELETE` queries.

You shoud use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE ID=?` to get what you want, as the docs say (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: `If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.`

Comment: Well yeah, apparently MySQL isn't one of them, and I believe that we're talking MySQL here.

Comment: ...and at any rate selecting everything just to check a row count is super inefficient.

Comment: I agree. Nevertheless MySQL does not give found `SELECT` rows via PDO's `rowCount()`